# Hover image not appearing while acting as submit button (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I've created a form which emails me the answers and all was fine until I tied to change to 'submit' button. I have a 'submit' image which is fine, but when I hover over it my hover image does not appear. Here's my code. Where am I going wrong?

```
/*buttons*/
.submitbut {
background: url("images/z_submit.jpg")  no-repeat; border: none;
display: block;
width: 62px;
height: 36px;

}
.submitbut:hover {
background: url("images/z_submit_roll.jpg")  no-repeat; border: none;
background-position: 0px -50px;
display: block;
width: 62px;
height: 36px;
}
```

and the html code i have is...

```
<input type="submit" class="submitbut" value="" />
```

Comment: Ahhh, sorry about the title. What a disaster. That was going to be my initial question until I looked it up on this site!

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/v3RYM/

Comment: are you sure `images/z_submit_roll.jpg` exists?

Comment: haha +1 using the google logo

Comment: THe title is a bit misleading...Reading your question, I understand that the css for the button is not showing right. Might have different reasons, like wrong path, wrong background positioning, etc.

Comment: Hey @user2482929 I submitted an edit for this post (i fixed your title) you just have to accept the edit so that it shows up for everybody. Welcome to StackOverflow btw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you could get rid of a couple declarations:

```css
.submitbut:hover {
    background: url("images/z_submit_roll.jpg")  no-repeat; border: none;
    background-position: 0px -50px;
}
```

Secondly, if it's not working, only two things can be wrong:

1. `images/z_submit_roll.jpg` doesn't exist, or;
2. You've shifted the `background-position` improperly.

Comment: Thanks Michael! I've knocked out the declarations and deleted the 50. Working a treat now. Cheers

Comment: @user2482929, I'm glad I could be of assistance!